# Getting this javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No X509TrustManager implementation available error in Jmeter, when opening Plugin manager

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm getting:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
```

I have added a Jar file for plugin manager 1.7 to it, for checking to perform the plugin. Earlier it was working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check [*system.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) of your JMeter installation for any occurrences of the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*` lines.
2. Once you detect them - remove them completely as you broke JMeter's SSL configuration completely
3. Once you remove them - restart JMeter to pick up the change

More information:

- [Plugins Manager Network Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: through keystore value I got the solution, it was corrupted